# Using JNI in Mono to Access Java Library

Tags: xamarin.android, urbanairship.com, jnienv

I am developing an app using mono for Android and have been strugelling to get the push notifications working, I am using Urban Airship.

So far I have been able to call TakeOff() and EnablePush() and my app is successfully registering, see the following code:

```
 //_____________________________
 // Get the airship config class
    IntPtr ip_airshipConfigOptions = JNIEnv.FindClass("com/urbanairship/AirshipConfigOptions");

   if (ip_airshipConfigOptions == IntPtr.Zero)
   {
         throw new InvalidOperationException("Counldn't find java class !");
   }

                //__________________________________________________
                // Get the loadDefaults method from the config class
                IntPtr methodId = JNIEnv.GetStaticMethodID(ip_airshipConfigOptions, "loadDefaultOptions", "(Landroid/content/Context;)Lcom/urbanairship/AirshipConfigOptions;");

                if (methodId == IntPtr.Zero)
                {
                    throw new InvalidOperationException("Couldn't find java class !");
                }

                //________________________________________________________________
                // Call the loadDefaultOptions method passing in this app instance
                var methodPtr = JNIEnv.CallStaticObjectMethod(ip_airshipConfigOptions, methodId, new JValue(this));

                //________________________
                // Get the UAirship class
                IntPtr ip_uairship = JNIEnv.FindClass("com/urbanairship/UAirship");

                if (ip_uairship == IntPtr.Zero)
                {
                    throw new InvalidOperationException("Couldn't find java class !");
                }

                //___________________________________________
                // Get takeOff method with configoption param
                IntPtr methodId2 = JNIEnv.GetStaticMethodID(ip_uairship, "takeOff", "(Landroid/app/Application;Lcom/urbanairship/AirshipConfigOptions;)V");

                //______________________________________________
                // Get takeOff method without configoption param
                //IntPtr methodId3 = JNIEnv.GetStaticMethodID(ip_uairship, "takeOff", "(Landroid/app/Application;)V");

                //___________________________________________________________________________________________
                // Call UAirship.takeOff(this, options). Not sure if these parameters are specified correctly 
                JNIEnv.CallStaticVoidMethod(ip_uairship, methodId2, new JValue(this), new JValue(methodPtr));

                //________________________________________
                // Enable Push in Urban Airship Pushmanager     
                IntPtr ip_pushmanager = JNIEnv.FindClass("com/urbanairship/push/PushManager");
                IntPtr ip_enablePush = JNIEnv.GetStaticMethodID(ip_pushmanager, "enablePush", "()V");
                JNIEnv.CallStaticVoidMethod(ip_pushmanager, ip_enablePush);
```

I now need to make a call to PushManager.shared().setIntentReciever(myClass) but I can't seem to access the shared() class or the setIntentReciever method. I have tried various combinations to try access the method but keep getting class/method not found exceptions.

```
//IntPtr ip_setReciver = JNIEnv.GetStaticMethodID(ip_PushManager, "shared().setIntentReceiver", "(Landroid/app/Class)V");
```

Any help with this is appreciated! I'm sure it can be solved with one line, I think I'm just missing something with the syntax.

Regards

Comment: Just for reference, the call from java looks like this: PushManager.shared().setIntentReceiver(IntentReceiver.class);

Answer (score 0):

Solved this issue, see the code below for calling setIntentReceiver via JNI:

```
//__________________________
// Get the PushManager class
IntPtr ip_Test = JNIEnv.FindClass("com/urbanairship/push/PushManager");

//_____________________
// Get the class object
IntPtr ip_class = JNIEnv.GetObjectClass(ip_Test);

//_________________________________
// Get the setIntentReciever method
IntPtr ip_setIntent = JNIEnv.GetMethodID(ip_Test, "setIntentReceiver", "(Ljava/lang/Class;)V");

//_________________________________________________
// Create a new jValue from the IntentRecieverClass
JValue val = new JValue(reciever.Class);

                //______________________________________________________________________________________
// Set the intent reciever by calling the setIntentReciever method passing in the jValue
JNIEnv.CallStaticVoidMethod(ip_class, ip_setIntent, val);
```